# Need to freeze animated object when it's clicked

Tags: javascript, animation, mouseclick-event

I am using javascript and three.js to animate dandelion seeds. See the live demo [here](https://wishchain.github.io/), it might help you understand. I am trying to make the seed stop when it's clicked. Here is my code.

```
                if (s.mesh.clicked === true){
                    console.log('hi')
                }else{
                    if(s.start === null) {s.start = timestamp};

                    s.progress = (timestamp - s.start) / s.duration / 1000;
                    if (i%2===0){
                        x = (s.progress * s.maxX/s.gridSize)-4;
                    } else if (i%3===0) {
                        x = (s.progress * s.maxX/s.gridSize)
                    } else {
                        x = (s.progress * s.maxX/s.gridSize)-8;
                    }
                    y = 2 * Math.sin(x);

                    s.mesh.position.x = Math.min(s.maxX, s.gridSize * x);
                    s.mesh.position.y = s.maxY/2 +(s.gridSize * y)*s.ampvar;

                    if(s.mesh.position.x >= 66){
                        s.start = null;
                        s.maxX = Math.random()*2 + 66;
                        s.maxY = Math.random()*45 - 20;
                        s.duration = Math.random()*2 + 7;
                        s.gridSize = Math.random()*10 + 5;
                        s.ampvar = Math.random()*0.15 + 0.05;

                    }
```

In my logic, this should work because if it was clicked it should skip over the code that makes it move, but it doesn't work. Does anyone have any tips for possible fixes?

[Full code here](https://github.com/wishchain/wishchain.github.io/blob/master/index.html)

Comment: I haven't read the whole code, but presumably this is a single step in the animation, and this gets called multiple times (once per frame).  You would only be skipping a single frame in this case, you need to set a flag instead which halts the animation loop.

Comment: @Ian Thanks for the reply. I don't understand why it would only skip a single frame, if s.mesh.clicked stays true. I also don't know how to go setting up a flag that halts the animation loop, because I only want one seed to freeze and the others to continue moving

Comment: Are you sure this flag stays set?  Have you tried debugging or setting a breakpoint in the code?

Comment: @Ian I console.log ('hi') if the flag is true and hundreds of 'hi's print so it stays set...unless I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: I was curious about this, so I looked at it some more.  I think the issue is with your event listener registration.  No matter which seed I clicked, or how early in the animation, I always got `seeds[19]` triggered.  If I wait long enough before clicking one, sure enough you can see one of them freezes (sometimes off screen) http://www.giphy.com/gifs/3pZft86uBQVFzIrErV
I can't replicate this locally easily, so I can't do much more remotely.  I'd be looking at your seed event listeners, to begin with set it to `console.log('you clicked on the seed ' + i)`

Comment: The more I look at it, the more crazy it seems.  I'd suggest try and simplify this to a very small test case, see if it still happens, and report it to ThreeX.  Looks like an event registration error.

Comment: @Ian I found the problem: I add the event listener to each seed in a for loop, so when a seed is clicked the computer no longer knows what the index is and will refer to the last known index, making whichever seed that is stop. This explains why you always got seeds[19] triggered. I posted a new question about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52008133/finding-the-index-of-a-clicked-object-on-the-canvas), if you happen to have expertise regarding this issue. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!