# Finding the index of a clicked object on the canvas

Tags: javascript, three.js, mouseclick-event

Edit: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/flouing/xdqu18sp/) is a simplified JSFiddle. The event listener is on line 60.

I'm using js and three.js to animate moving dandelion seeds, and I need to stop a seed if it is clicked. I'm adding an event listener to each seed, like so:

```
for (var i = 0; i < seeds.length; i++) {
    s=seeds[i];
    domEvents.addEventListener(seeds[i].mesh, 'click', function(event){
        s.clicked = true;
        console.log('you clicked on the mesh');
        $('#id01').modal('show');
    }, false);
}
```

The problem is that when a seed is clicked, the computer no longer knows what 's' or seeds[i] is, because the loop has ended. If I manually add an event listener to each seed, then the seeds stop correctly. This is inefficient however. It would be 19 blocks of this, with the only change being the number:

```
    domEvents.addEventListener(seeds[1].mesh, 'click', function(event){
        seeds[1].clicked = true;
        $('#id01').modal('show');
    }, false);
```

My code to stop the seed is the following:

```
        if (s.clicked === true) {
            console.log('hi');
            s.mesh.position.x = s.currentX;
            s.mesh.position.y = s.currentY;
        } else { run the code that moves the seed
```

The code to stop the seed works, but for the wrong seed. It stops whichever seed was last added to the seeds array.

[See the full code here](https://github.com/wishchain/wishchain.github.io/blob/master/index.html)

Is there an efficient way to add the event listener correctly to each seed? How could I know the index of the clicked seed?

Comment: In your first block of code, instead of `s.clicked = true`, something like `this.clicked = true;` will maintain the referential integrity long after `s` and `seeds` go out of scope.  Your click event, once it's associated to the element, only needs `this` to know itself. Using that principle, you should be able to clean this up accordingly

Comment: @Marc When I tried setting this.clicked = true, s.clicked did not register as true later on. I tried reading up on the this keyword and am kind of lost. How could I use it correctly in my code?

Comment: I suggest creating a JSFiddle and linking it here so potential solution providers can have a partially working example to help you.

Comment: @Marc Thanks, I updated my post with one.